# What is the logical way of querying for Rooms in Firebase

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am not sure if I'm asking this question the right way, but I'll try to explain.
So I am making a mobile application in which a user can create a room with the credentials `roomname` and `roompassword`:

- get the `roomname` and the `roompassword` from a Form
- create a document with the given `roomname`: `/rooms/roomname/users/uid/`. If `roomname` exists, don't create the room.

And a user can enter a room like this:

- get the `roomname` and the `roompassword` from a Form
- query if `roomname` document exists in `/rooms` collection, check if password field matches with the `roompassword` you get from the form, if true, add the user to room.

So I am wondering if I should keep the `roomname` automatically generated and create a field called `roomname` that I can query, or the way I do it is fine? Also security is not a priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using the room name as a field or as an identifier is the same thing. It depends on how you want to handle your code. Because if the roomname is a field then you'll have to loop through the all the rooms and check for the room field == to the one you want the user to enter. However, if the roomname is the key, then all you do is get it from room list and compare. But i usually try to avoid the **automatically generated** stuff, they make disasters.

wish you good luck